# VPS public ip is not browsable, Curl works on VPS but not on my desktop

Tags: linux, firewall

Following command returns the correct response on my linux/centos vps terminal but not works on my personal computer terminal:

```
curl http://x.x.x.x:1337/api/
```

or

```
curl http://example.com:1337/api/
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Is your personal computer behind a proxy? Can you ping the host?

Comment: Is the port open to the outside world?

Comment: @xenoid in my personal computer I can ping the host, but not with port.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch I use centos 7. firewallD is not running.

Answer (score -1):

Solution is here:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1337 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
```

Replace `1337` with your port.